# Using raster to calculate the mean application and total application of pesticides, but numbers not adding up

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I use a raster file that has global application rate (which is in kg/hectare) of glyphosate to soybeans in 2015. I want to calculate the mean application rate for each country and also get the total application in kg.

I have tried to extract the data but when I check it it doesn't add up so I would need some help on where I am going wrong.

Here is my code:

```
## Load libraries and read data ----
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(maptools) # To get the borders of countries

# Border of countries
data(wrld_simpl)

# Make a data frame to put my numbers on the corresponding countries
world_data_empty = data.frame(country = wrld_simpl$NAME, iso3c = wrld_simpl$ISO3)

# This is a file with the application rate of glyphosate to soybeans in 2015 in kg/ha
raster_path = "https://raw.github.com/hansronald/Pesticide-data/master/APR_Soybean_Glyphosate_2015_L.tif"
sqm_to_ha_conversion = 0.0001
rast <- raster(raster_path)

## Extract the raster data ----

# Remove all the negative values of the raster
# This is because negative values correspond to things like water and I dont want them to count when adding, replace with NAs
# Then trim to remove NAs
rast_positive = rast
rast_positive <- clamp(rast, lower=0, useValues=FALSE)
rast_trimmed = trim(rast_positive)

# Multiply the kg/ha with the area of each cell to get the total kgs
rast_total_pesticide_application = rast_trimmed * area(rast_trimmed)

# Get the mean applcation rate (kg/ha) for each country
mean_application_rate_extract = raster::extract(rast_trimmed, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE) # sp = T for keeping original dataframe

# Get the total applcation rate (kg/ha) for each country
total_application_extract = raster::extract(rast_total_pesticide_application, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

# Get the total area 
total_area_extract = raster::extract(area(rast_trimmed), wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

## Create the data frame ----

# Put the mean pesticide use per country in a dataframe and name the column after the pesticide
# NaNs created because all raster cells are NA in country polygon, replace with 0
mean_application_rate_extract[is.nan(mean_application_rate_extract)] = 0
mean_application_rate = data.frame(mean_application_rate = mean_application_rate_extract)
total_application = data.frame(total_application = total_application_extract)
total_area = data.frame(total_area = total_area_extract)

world_data = data.frame(world_data_empty, mean_application_rate, total_application, total_area) %>% 
  as_tibble()

# Check calculations by selecting a few countries and multiplying apr*area
world_data %>% 
  filter(iso3c %in% c("CHN", "BRA", "USA")) %>% 
  mutate(total_application_calc = mean_application_rate * total_area)
```

Here is the output

```
  country       iso3c mean_application_rate total_application total_area total_application_calc
  <fct>         <fct>                 <dbl>             <dbl>      <dbl>                  <dbl>
1 Brazil        BRA                    2.00          4253187.     84469.                168653.
2 China         CHN                    2.09          9153007.     93254.                194736.
3 United States USA                    1.93          5070446.     93889.                181164.
```

So there are a few problems here. First is that total_application_calc should be equal to total application (as it is the application rate (kg/ha) multiplied by total area (ha).

But the problem is also that the total application seem to be of with at lest one order of magnitude. According to [this data](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5044953/) the total application of glyphosate on soybeans in 2014 was 122,473,987 pounds which is equal to 55,553,266 kg compared to the 5,070,446 that I get from this dataset. It's ok if it is slightly off as they are different sources with different assumptions, but not this much.

Can anyone help where I might have done things wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified your code a bit, and I think the numbers make more sense now. I cannot speak to the external validity question.

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
data(wrld_simpl)

r <- raster("https://raw.github.com/hansronald/Pesticide-data/master/APR_Soybean_Glyphosate_2015_L.tif")
r <- clamp(r, lower=0, useValues=FALSE)

# area in ha
a <- area(r) * 100

mean_app <- raster::extract(r, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
rtot  <- r * a
tot_app  <- raster::extract(rtot, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I think you made a mistake here. You need to use the cells that are not NA only.

```
rarea <- mask(a, r)
tot_area <- raster::extract(rarea, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
## not 
## tot_area <- raster::extract(area(r), wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Inspect the results

```
w <- data.frame(country = wrld_simpl$NAME, iso3c = wrld_simpl$ISO3,
                mean_app=mean_app, tot_app=tot_app, tot_area=tot_area)
w$tot_calc <- w$tot_area * w$mean_app
w[is.na(w)] <- 0

w[w$iso3c %in% c("CHN", "BRA", "USA"), ]
#          country iso3c mean_app   tot_app  tot_area  tot_calc
#21         Brazil   BRA 1.996631 425318662 213982181 427243427
#30          China   CHN 2.088219 915300667 439036703 916804725
#209 United States   USA 1.929559 507044556 263544939 508525402
  
global_app <- cellStats(rtot, "sum")
global_app
# 2375398749

sum(w$tot_app)
# 2367120358
```

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate the help. Only one things thats confusing me is why you divide the area with 100? According to the documentation of area a RasterLayer cell value is in km2. Since 1 km2 is 100 hectare, shouldn't it be multiplied with 100 instead? Or where have I gone wrong?