# How do I replicate this raster script using terra (specifically struggling with the mask function)?

Tags: r, raster, terra

I want to extract some application rates, total application and the area from a raster file containing pesticide use. I have many files where I need to do this and raster is to slow so I need to do it in terra instead but struggling to replicate the mask function.

Here is the code in raster (copied from here: [Using raster to calculate the mean application and total application of pesticides, but numbers not adding up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64727728/using-raster-to-calculate-the-mean-application-and-total-application-of-pesticid)):

```
library(tidyverse)

## With raster ----
data(wrld_simpl)
r <- raster::raster("https://raw.github.com/hansronald/Pesticide-data/master/APR_Soybean_Glyphosate_2015_L.tif")
r <- raster::clamp(r, lower=0, useValues=FALSE)

# area in ha
a <- raster::area(r) * 100

## Get the mean application rate
mean_app <- raster::extract(r, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
rtot  <- r * a

## Get the total application for each country
tot_app  <- raster::extract(rtot, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

## Get the total area for each country
rarea <- mask(a, r)
tot_area <- raster::extract(rarea, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

In terra

```
## Terra ----

data(wrld_simpl)
wrld_simpl = vect(wrld_simpl)

r <- terra::rast("https://raw.github.com/hansronald/Pesticide-data/master/APR_Soybean_Glyphosate_2015_L.tif")
r <- terra::clamp(r, lower=0, values=FALSE)

# area in ha
a <- terra::area(r) * 100

mean_app <- terra::extract(r, wrld_simpl, fun = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
rtot  <- r * a
tot_app  <- terra::extract(rtot, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)

rarea <- terra::mask(a, r)
tot_area <- terra::extract(rarea, wrld_simpl, fun = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But I get this error when I try to use mask:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘mask’ for signature ‘"numeric", "SpatRaster"’
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `area` method in `terra` is a bit different than in `raster`. In `terra` it can return either a SpatRaster (area for each cell) or a number (the total area). In your case `a` is the total area, and there should be no surprise that you cannot use it with `mask` (it is of course good to inspect the objects at each step.)

You can get what you want by using `sum=FALSE`. And by adding `mask=TRUE` you can skip the mask step altogether.

```
a <- terra::area(r, sum=FALSE, mask=TRUE) / 10000
```

Also note that the unit is m<sup>2</sup>.